# ExtJs 4 custom Ext.toolbar.Paging

Tags: extjs4

I need to implement custom paging appearance which should looks something like this:

[image: Sorry fo my bad paintings]

My main question is what approach is better:
extend from Ext.toolbar.Paging and try to change it appearance or create my own view which will have reference to store and will trigger all actions according to user clicks on this view.

I definitelly know that I can go with 2nd approach but I also wondering if it is possible to change default paging toolbar to fit desired appearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that the most natural way of doing this is to create plugin for original Paging class, this plugin changes appearance (hide unaccessary elements and add new buttons)

Comment: Hi :) any example of how you implemented this ?

Comment: can you please provide any reference link for help for that because I also need same paging

Comment: Thanks in advance please help me I am stuck on this last four days